# Deep equal object comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, recursion

Am reading Eloquent javascript and I was given a task to write a deep equal function for objects.

My code works well for object without nested object but when i pass two object that has a nested object in it my code fails.

i tried debugging it and i noticed that anytime the function encounters a nested object, it doesn't transfer control back to the main object.

Take for example i have two object a and b below:

```json
let a = {
  name: "ade",
  last: "segun",
  dead: {
    name: "ade",
    last: "segun",
  },
  eaten: true,
};

let b = {
  name: "ade",
  last: "segun",
  dead: {
    name: "ade",
    last: "segun",
  },
  eaten: false,
};
```

After the function checks for the dead property which is a nested object, it doesn't return to the main object and checks for `eaten` property.

What did I do wrong? This is My code

```js
let a = { name: "ade", last: "segun", dead: { name: "ade", last: "segun", }, eaten: true, }; 
let b = { name: "ade", last: "segun", dead: { name: "ade", last: "segun", }, eaten: false, };


const deepEqual = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const keysA = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keysB = Object.keys(obj2);
  if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) {
    return false;
  }
  let c;
  for (let key of keysA) {
    // c checks whether the key is part of keysB array
    c = keysB[keysB.indexOf(key)];
    if (key !== c) {
      return false;
    }
    if (
      typeof obj1[key] === "object" &&
      typeof obj2[c] === "object" &&
      obj1[key] !== null &&
      obj2[c] !== null
    ) {
      return deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[c]);
    } else {
      if (obj1[key] !== obj2[c]) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(deepEqual(a, b)); //true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your code...

```
return deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[c]);
```

... basically makes the comparison function to *stop* when the first nested object is encountered. What should happen instead is 1) result of deepEqual is calculated, and 2) only if it's `false`, the function returns it immediately. For example:

```
const isDeeplyEqual = deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[c]);
if (!isDeeplyEqual) return false;
```

... or just:

```
if (!deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[c])) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your code. You saved me so much time. Exactly what I needed. But my implementation was to find the deep difference between two objects.

I just had to edit the code a little. I will drop it for someone that might have the same issue I was trying to solve

```
    const differenceObj = {
    };

    const deepEqual = (obj1: any, obj2: any) => {
        const keysA = Object.keys(obj1);
        const keysB = Object.keys(obj2);
        if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) {
            return false;
        }
        let c;
        for (const key of keysA) {
            c = keysB[keysB.indexOf(key)];
            if (key !== c) {
                return false;
            }
            if (
                typeof obj1[key] === 'object' &&
                typeof obj2[c] === 'object' &&
                obj1[key] !== null &&
                obj2[c] !== null
            ) {
                deepEqual(obj1[key], obj2[c]);
            }
            if (obj1[key] !== obj2[c]) {
                differenceObj[key] = {
                    new: obj1[key],
                    old: obj2[key],
                };
            }
        }

        return differenceObj;
    
}
```

I had to return the old and the new values which represents the differences.